# How to detect the internet connection when I close my modem while keep the router open?

Tags: objective-c, ios, internet-connection

I use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from App Developer Library to check the internet connection, the code is as below:

```
+(BOOL)reachable {
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];

Reachability *r1 = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
NetworkStatus internetStatus1 = [r1 currentReachabilityStatus];

Reachability *r2 = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:FTPURL];
NetworkStatus internetStatus2 = [r2 currentReachabilityStatus];

DLog(@"%d,%d,%d",internetStatus,internetStatus1,internetStatus2);

if(internetStatus != NotReachable && internetStatus1 != NotReachable && internetStatus2 != NotReachable) 
{
    return YES;
}

return NO;
```

}

If the wifi is available, the three status are sure to be "Reachable". If I turn off the wifi manually (Network connection flag is off), all of the three status are"NOTReachable".

When I turn off the Modem, while keep the wireless router open (Network connection flag is on). Although I can not access internet, all of the three status are still "Reachable". I want to know why this happen and how to detect this UnReachable statu?

Comment: I have the same issue , did you find why?!

Answer (score 2):

There is no distinction as far as your iPhone is concerned between a very small network (i.e. your wireless LAN) and the Internet.  All it can say for certain is that it has a connection to a TCP/IP network.  It has no way of telling how big that network is.

If you want to find out for certain if your server is reachable from any particular iPhone, you must try to connect to it.  Even then, it might disappear between you testing the connection and sending real data.  So whether you test for a connection or not before you start, you still have to handle loss of the connection gracefully during data transmission.  You might as well not bother checking in advance and just assume it's there and have good code for handling transmission errors.